# fill datagridview with info from dataset

Tags: c#, datagridview, dataset

I have a problem filling datagridview with text/values from dataset (NOT MYSQL!!).

I have dataset table filled when .xml file is imported.

```
DataSet1 dsDataSet1 = new DataSet1();
String XMLCompanies = Application.StartupPath + @"\XMLCompanies.xml";

dsDataSet1.ReadXml(XMLCompanies);
```

I am trying to display content of dataset in datagridview so I add line:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet1.Tables["Companies"];
```

however I only get rows headers names but without any other data.

XMLCompanies.xml data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="true"?>
-<DataSet1 xmlns="http://tempuri.org/DataSet1.xsd">
-<Companies>
<ID>1234</ID>
<Company>TEST inc</Company>
<Address>Address test</Address>
<ZIP>12345678</ZIP>
<City>City TEST</City>
<TAXnumber>70769232</TAXnumber>
</Companies>
</DataSet1>
```

Any simple solution to display dataset text/values in datagridview would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**XMLCompanies.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<DataSet1 xmlns="http://tempuri.org/DataSet1.xsd">
  <Companies>
    <ID>1234</ID>
    <Company>TEST inc</Company>
    <Address>Address test</Address>
    <ZIP>12345678</ZIP>
    <City>City TEST</City>
    <TAXnumber>70769232</TAXnumber>
  </Companies>
</DataSet1>
```

**Code:**

```
  DataSet xmlDataSet = new DataSet();
  String XMLCompanies = Application.StartupPath + @"\XMLCompanies.xml";
  xmlDataSet.ReadXml(XMLCompanies);
  this.dataGridView1.DataSource = xmlDataSet.Tables[0];
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your anwser. What is namespace for DataBind ? I get an underline :/

Comment: @MatejMerc your application is Asp.net rigt?

Comment: It's c# windows forms application

Comment: @MatejMerc Check modified answer!

Comment: I get only headers names

Comment: are you sure? am getting the output. check your XML is correct as mine, also your GridView

Comment: I deleted old gridview and added new one. Now it works! thanks alot!